# HP 2000-bf69WM doesn't wake from sleep after downgrading to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep, power-management, uefi

I have an HP 2000-bf69WM laptop that originally shipped with Windows 8. I have since downgraded it to Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1.

I have installed all the drivers from HP's website for the laptop, even though they specified that they were for Windows 8, they installed and seem to be working without issue.

Everything seems to be working correctly, however whenever the computer enters sleep mode, it will not wake. The caps lock key blinks once, slowly, which according to [this HP support article](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01732674&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en#N399), that means "CPU not functional".

Hybrid Sleep is off, and I have the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) enabled in the BIOS.

The output of `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` is completely blank, so this means that no devices are currently capable of waking the computer from sleep.

In addition to this, none of the devices in the Device Manager have the "Power Management" tab like I believe they should.

```
C:\>powercfg -devicequery wake_programmable
Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller

C:\>powercfg -devicequery wake_from_any
Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller
Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller (001)
Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
UMBus Enumerator
USB Root Hub
ATI I/O Communications Processor PCI Bus Controller
PCI standard PCI-to-PCI bridge
USB Root Hub (001)
USB Root Hub (002)
USB Root Hub (003)
PCI standard PCI-to-PCI bridge (001)
Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller
Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller (001)
```

Does anyone know why this could be? Possibly a driver issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just because the drivers installed does not mean Windows 7 support.  The ability to be woken from a sleep state is entire handled by drivers.  The behavior you describe seems to be because your using Windows 7.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, that would make sense. Do you know perhaps what driver handles power management, or do all the drivers of each device handle it individually? If so I could look for some drivers that are meant for Windows 7.

Comment: Most of the Intel/AMD Chipset drivers handle this behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, I have not tried installing those, and they weren't on HP's site. I will install them and see how it goes, thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound Installing AMD chipset drivers helped, thank you very much! Feel free to post that as the answer so that you get credit.